# XML - XSLT Not retrieving data from XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

When i run my xslt document it gives me the table headers but is not  retrieving data from the XML document. I am using Aptana studio 3. I have posted my XML code and XSLT code below.

Here is my xml code, basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>

<fruits>
<fruit>
    <name>Avocados</name>
    <origin>Central America</origin>
</fruit>
<fruit>
    <name>Bananas</name>
    <origin>Southeast Asia</origin>
</fruit>
<fruit>
    <name>Blackberries</name>
    <origin>Europe</origin>
</fruit>
<fruit>
    <name>Cherrys</name>
    <origin>Asia</origin>
</fruit>
<fruit>
    <name>Pawpaw</name>
    <origin>North America</origin>
</fruit>
</fruits>
```

Here is my xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL  /Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Fruit</th>
                    <th>Origin</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="/fruits/fruit">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="origin" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
             </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your actual XML has an `xmlns` declaration and that you are ignoring in your XSLT.

Comment: @Tomalak may you elaborate just a little bit more on this. I have ran this on a online XML editor and it does retrieve the data but when i run it on Aptana it does not.

Comment: So... *does* your input XML contain an `xmlns` declaration?

Comment: @Tomalak that shouldn't matter. I'm pulling the tag not the namespace. Though, thanks for your help. I figured it out.

Comment: Of course it matters. The "tag" and the namespace are an inseparable union. You cannot look at them as two different things, they are one thing.